# how to add dynamic website on google search engine?

Tags: search-engine

It's like I have 1,000,000. links, How can I add to all of the Google search engine?

E,g

```
www.site.com/s/!#/songs/songs_id/songs_name/
```

meta tag---

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
<meta name="description" content="hashchange description">
<meta name="keywords" content="hashchange keywords">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="robots" CONTENT="all">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days">
<meta name="author" content="author name">
<meta name="rating" content="general">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://site.com/hashchange links">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: For reference, everything after that `#` in your URLs will almost certainly be parsed as a "fragment identifier", which is a purely client-side thing.  Don't be surprised if no links to the individual songs show up in Google, and you end up with one link to the URL in your `<link rel=canonical>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google ignores meta tags completely, so you might as well remove them. You can submit a sitemap.xml to google's webmaster service. But what you really need is people linking to you. Then you'll be top of google.